# DynamoDB - "INSERT INTO / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I have the following MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (email,attempts,passwords) VALUES (?,0,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attempts=0,time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;',
```

The key is **email**, so the query translates into:

```
Add new row to table_a
email = email, attempts = 0, passwords = passwords
IF row for email already exists then
update attempts = 0, time = current_time
// "passwords" isn't changed if its an update. Only on insert.
```

My initial approach to doing this in DynamoDB was:

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'table_a',
    Key: { 'email': { 'S': email } },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET attempts = :a, loginTime = :lt, passwords = :pw',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':a': {N: '0'},
        ':lt': {S: new Date().toISOString()},
        ':pw': {S: myPw},
};

ddb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // do error stuff
    } else {
        // do success stuff
    }
});
```

But I made a mistake, and with the above code, the **passwords** is updated **every single time**. So I modified my code, but I feel like I am just hacking it, by doing a fall-through statement like this:

```
// Add row with email, date, pw - if email PK doesn't exist
const insertParams = {
    TableName: process.env.DDB_LOGIN_LOGS_TABLE,
    Item: {
        'email' : {S: email},
        'attempts' : {N: '0'},
        'loginTime': {S: new Date().toISOString()},
        'passwords': {S: myPw},
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(email)',
};
const updateParams = {
    TableName: 'table_a',
    Key: { 'email': { 'S': email } },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET attempts = :a, loginTime = :lt',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':a': {N: '0'},
        ':lt': {S: new Date().toISOString()},
};

ddb.putItem(insertParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        ddb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // do error stuff
            } else {
                // do success stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a better (correct) way of writing that logic?